# which of this html markup is more right

Tags: html, markup, web-crawler, html-heading

I have a HTML markup for each brand in my page like this

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a title="mallname" href="/brand/mallname">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/Images/mallname.png" alt="mallname" />
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                <h2>mallname</h2>
            </div>
        </a>   
    </li>
</ul>
```

is that `heading` position ok inside a `hyperlink`, or should I change it to

```
<ul>
    <li>    
        <h2>
            <a title="mallname" href="/brand/mallname">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="/Images/mallname.png" alt="mallname" />
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                    mallname
                </div>
            </a>   
        </h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

which one is the more right way to write it, and what is the result that will be read by `crawler` for the `heading` in both case?

If in the first one, the `heading` content is only `mallname`, will the second one be read as `mallname mallname mallname` as there is a `title` attribute in the `hyperlink` and `alt` attribute in the `image` inside the `heading`

here's one of the result of the `list item`

[image: Result Image]

Comment: What did **your test** tell you about the outcome?

Comment: @Fildor, what did you mean by my test? currently I was using the first one in the live environment, but am confused which to use when told about the other way to write it.

Comment: Did you just try it out? You should then see what is the outcome and decide if it is what you want. If both is valid html, then more right is what gives the wanted Output, right?

Comment: @Fildor It's been about 6 month that I have used the first one, the result (ui) is the same with both way. So both way to write it is valid, but what will crawler in the `heading` for the 2nd way, is it just text inside the `div` or the `title` and `alt` attribute will be seen as a `heading` too? and will it have any effect for seo?

Comment: Ah, now I see. I totally misunderstood the question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, the `h2` doesn’t describe the content of the `li`. In scope of this heading is everything following it, until the next heading starts. So in fact, the previous heading would describe the following content, and so on. This problem always arises when using headings without sectioning elements in lists.

In your second example, the `h2` probably contains more than it should (two times "mallname"; the one in the `title` attribute is not considered to be part of the heading content). But what is the actual content here? There is only a heading, which doesn’t seem to make sense.

Your `alt` content is probably not correct/useful. When it is exactly the same as the corresponding heading, the you should probably use an empty `alt` value. But it’s likely that the image represents something in addition to the heading: describe this in the `alt` content.

Duplicating the heading content in the `title` attribute doesn’t seem to make sense, either. Only use it for additional helpful (but not essential) content.

So you should use something else: sectioning elements. Judging from the screenshot, it might be the case that `article` is appropriate (if not, use `section`).

By using a sectioning element like `article`, the heading doesn’t have to be placed on the top.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <article>
      <a href="/brand/mallname">
        <img src="/Images/mallname.png" alt="Mallname offers … and …. It’s ….">
        <h2>mallname</h2>
      </a>
    </article>
  </li>
</ul>
```

However, use this only when the `h2` describes the `ìmg`! When the image is only an alternative to the heading (or only decoration, and the actual image content isn’t relevant in this context), why use headings at all? In that case you’d have just a list of links:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/brand/mallname"><img src="/Images/mallname.png" alt=""> mallname</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your clarification, if my page only consist of `list item` with your recommended `markup`, is it appropriate to use the either `article` or `section` for every item, is it better to use `<h1>` or `<h2>` for that, and is it ok to have many `article` in one page, because my page `(dynamic)` contains an average of 350 item with these `markup`

Comment: @Kyojimaru: If it’s only a list of links (with or without non-essential image), don’t use a sectioning element for each entry (this would be my second example). If each entry contains content (this would be my first example), you can use `h1` or the appropriate heading level (`h2`-`h6`). There is no restriction on how many `article` elements may be used on a page, but there is most definitely some limit for your users after which it gets hard to use/read it, right?

Answer (score 1):

Inside of `<ul>` should go `<li>` tags, so I think the first markup is more right, if to close eyes on the `<div>` elements inside of `<a>`.
Set your `<a>` to `display: block;` and you'll be correct with the first one.

Comment: sorry, it was a typing mistake, the `<li>` tag is outside of `heading`, edited the question

Comment: Why are you not using the actual code instead of typing a rough approximation of what you had? This is a great way to annoy fellow SO users!

Comment: @Lee well, sorry about. It's my actual code in the 1st code, even though it's stripped from any unnecesarry long attribute. And as for the 2nd code, it's what I would like to know which way is better, so there's my typing mistake there between `<li>` and `<h2>` because my actual code is using the 1st one. Sorry again for my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `<ul>` tags that are required as a parent for the `<li>`-tags.

Assuming you'd add the `<ul>`-tags that are missing: `<ul>` is not allowed as a child element for `<h2>` so that renders the second version as no good => **first one is "more right"**.

**The tests**, I took the liberty to add the missing `<ul>`'s & mandatory parents, the doctype is HTML5:

[W3C markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/) gives green light for this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head><title>tets</title></head><body>
<ul><li>
    <a title="mallname" href="/brand/mallname">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="/Images/mallname.png" alt="mallname" />
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <h2>mallname</h2>
        </div>
    </a>   
</li></ul>
</body></html>
```

[W3C markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/) gives the aforementioned error to this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head><title>tets</title></head><body>
<h2><ul>    
    <li>
        <a title="mallname" href="/brand/mallname">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/Images/mallname.png" alt="mallname" />
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                mallname
            </div>
        </a>   
    </li>
</ul></h2>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Okay.. now you changed the HTML content of the question so this answer is no longer valid.

Comment: sorry for the change, should have type it more carefully next time